# Accessing validation message from model at controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, model

How can one access model's validation message through ModelState variable at the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string message = ModelState["SomeProperty"].Errors[0].ErrorMessage;
```

Of course checks must be done as each of those accessors could simply return null. But if you are absolutely sure that `SomeProperty` has at least one error message in modelstate it's OK.

Those checks could of course be encapsulated in an extension method so that in your controller you could simply:

```
string message = ModelState.GetFirstErrorMessageFor("SomeProperty");
```

Like this for example:

```
public static class ModelStateExtensions
{
    public static string GetFirstErrorMessageFor(this ModelStateDictionary modelState, string property)
    {
        ModelState value;
        if (!modelState.TryGetValue(property, out value))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        return (value.Errors.FirstOrDefault() ?? new ModelError("")).ErrorMessage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you could `Join()` all of them.

Comment: @SLaks, yes, depending on the specific needs many things are possible.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `ModelState["PropertyName"].Errors` collection.